# Excel: Count unique comma-delimited strings in a column with countifs-style criteria from other columns

Tags: vba, excel

Hoping for help form an Excel/VBA wizard on this problem. I have a possible vision of what i need, but lack the expertise to pull it off.

Essentially the problem combines the use of a countifs formula (with multiple criteria) along with counting unique strings in a column containing comma-delimited strings like this:

```
Criteria1 | Criteria2 |Names
A         | X         |Bob
B         | Y         |Cam;Bob
A         | Y         |Dan;Ava
A         | Y         |Ava;Cam
```

^In this super-simplified example, it would be like counting unique names where Criteria1 = A & criteria2 = Y. Answer = 3 (Cam, Dan, Ava)

So far, i've been able to find a VBA solution (from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/437952-counting-unique-values-seperate-comma.html))that counts unique strings in a given column like "names" above, but I don't know how to combine that with countifs-style criteria to only pass certain parts of the names range to that function.

I have created an xlsm spreadsheet that further elaborates on the problem with better sample data, expected results and the partial VBA solution I have so far:

[xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttrqvgismgsj41a/SampleforUDFproblem.xlsx?dl=0)

edit: I'm using Excel 2013

edit2: uploaded xlsx in addition to xlsm. VBA code i'm currently using is below. Note that I copied this form another source and I don't really understand how the scripting.dictionary stuff works :/

```
Function cntunq(ByVal rng As Range)

' http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/437952-counting-unique-values-seperate-comma.html

Dim cl As Range, i As Integer
Dim dic1, ar
ar = Split(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(rng), ";"), vbLf, ""), ";")
Debug.Print Join(ar, ";")
Set dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic1.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
    dic1(ar(i)) = ""
Next i
cntunq = dic1.Count

End Function
```

Edit3: The above code just does the counting of unique values in a given range with ;-delimited strings. The part i don't know is how to modify this to take paramArray of conditions

Comment: There are not many who will download an xslm file.  It could contain detrimental code.  Please post the code you have tried directly in the Original post and explain what specifically it is doing that is in error.

Comment: I would use split and a dictionary to get the list of unique names. Then return the number of items in the dictionary as the answer.

Comment: If I find time I'm going to have a little fun with this one :-)

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for the comment regarding risky xslm download. I've uploaded an xlsx instead and will post the VBA to the original via edit. As for your suggestion, I don't really understand how to implement that, but it sounds like that achieves the count unique strings part, without the multiple criteria from other columns part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in a UDF using a dictionary:

```
Function MyCount(critRng As Range, crit As String, critRng2 As Range, crit2 As String, cntRng As Range, delim As String) As Long
Dim critarr(), critarr2(), cntarr()
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

critarr = critRng.Value
cntarr = cntRng.Value
critarr2 = critRng2.Value
If UBound(critarr, 1) <> UBound(cntarr, 1) Then Exit Function
For i = LBound(critarr, 1) To UBound(critarr, 1)
    If critarr(i, 1) = crit And critarr2(i, 1) = crit2 Then
        splt = Split(cntarr(i, 1), delim)
        For j = LBound(splt) To UBound(splt)
            On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add splt(j), splt(j)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next j
    End If
Next i
MyCount = dict.Count
End Function
```

Put that in a module and you would call it like a formula:

```
=MyCount($A$2:$A$5,"A",$B$2:$B$5,"Y",$C$2:$C$5,";")
```

[image]

---

Edit as per Comments

This will allow an Array entry, which will allow many conditions:

```
Function MyCount2(delim As String, rsltArr()) As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim splt() As String
Dim i&, j&
For i = LBound(rsltArr, 1) To UBound(rsltArr, 1)
    If rsltArr(i, 1) <> "False" And rsltArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
        splt = Split(rsltArr(i, 1), delim)
        For j = LBound(splt) To UBound(splt)
            On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add splt(j), splt(j)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next j
    End If
Next i
MyCount2 = dict.Count
End Function
```

This then is entered as the following array formula:

```
=MyCount2(";",IF(($A$2:$A$5="A")*($B$2:$B$5="Y"),$C$2:$C$5))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

If you want more criteria, then add another Boolean multiply to the existing in the first criterion of the IF() statement. So if you wanted to test if column Z was greater than 0 you would add `* ($Z$2:$Z$5>0)` after the column B test.

[image]

---

Here is a non array formula that uses ParamArray.

```
Function MyCount3(cntrng As Range, delim As String, ParamArray t()) As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim cntArr As Variant
cntArr = cntrng.Value
Dim tArr() As Boolean
Dim splt() As String
Dim I&, l&
Dim tpe As String
ReDim tArr(1 To t(0).Rows.Count)

For l = 1 To t(0).Rows.Count
    For I = LBound(t) To UBound(t) Step 2
        If Not tArr(l) Then
            If InStr("<>=", Left(t(I + 1), 1)) = 0 Then t(I + 1) = "=" & t(I + 1)
            If InStr("<>=", Mid(t(I + 1), 2, 1)) > 0 Then Z = 2 Else Z = 1
            tArr(l) = Application.Evaluate("NOT(""" & t(I).Item(l).Value & """" & Left(t(I + 1), Z) & """" & Mid(t(I + 1), Z + 1) & """)")
      End If
    Next I
Next l

For l = 1 To UBound(tArr)
    If Not tArr(l) Then
        splt = Split(cntArr(l, 1), delim)
        For j = LBound(splt) To UBound(splt)
            On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add splt(j), splt(j)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next j
    End If
Next l
MyCount3 = dict.Count
End Function
```

It is entered similar to SUMIFS,COUNTIFS.

The first criterion is the range that needs to be split and counted.

The second is the delimiter on which it should split.

Then the rest is entered in pairs.

```
=MyCount3($C$2:$C$5,";",$A$2:$A$5,"A",$B$2:$B$5,"Y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help...interesting solution. Would there be a way to modify this to take additional criteria without hardcoding in more critrng and crit arguments and hadnling them with if statements? Kind of like how countifs lets you supply any number of criteria pairs...

Comment: It could be modified to use and Array formula IF.  If I get the time I will modify it.

Comment: @CBrown19 see edit.  You may need to refresh your screen.  Remember to mark one of the answers as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Choose the answer that you use.

Comment: Amazing! That second function works really well. I totally understand how the if statement array formula works...wish i'd though of it, though i would've tripped up on the vba logic to handle the array for sure. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ScottCraner as you know I'm new here, but typically if an answer is posted and accepted we don't post a new answer?

Comment: @JReid Feel free to answer.  It may be a better answer.  The OP can always change the "correct" answer.  Even if the OP does not change it may get upvotes.  Also, remember why this site is here, Stack Overflow is a searchable repository of information for those who have questions.  Your answer may help a future reader.

Comment: @CBrown19 I just added a ParamArray version, no need for the array IF.

Comment: @ScottCraner Love that you posted another version using paramArray...very interesting and educational. I ran into an issue with it however. One of the tests i want to perform on my real data involves wildcards where a test condition pair could look like `$B$2:$B$5,"*"&$E$2&"*"`. This produces an error when i use the new function.

Comment: As a further aside, I liked the array formula option because it also allowed flexibility with AND and OR logic by multiplying or adding the criteria

Comment: Continuing from thoughts above, i know that a countifs function can handle OR logic by using a static array in a parameter pair like `$A$2:$A$5,{"A","B"}` That doesn't seem possible with your function, but maybe that's adjustable?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, 1) = "A" And Cells(i, 2) = "Y" Then
            arr = Split(Cells(i, 3), ";")
                For Each a In arr
                    On Error Resume Next
                        c.Add a, CStr(a)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next a
        End If
    Next i      
    MsgBox c.Count      
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. To satisfy my problem, this would need to be changed from a sub to a function and modified to take multiple criteria and criteria ranges in the function arguments, kinda like the worksheet formulas countifs or sumifs.

Comment: @CBrown19  Then I would start with ***Scott's*** code and extend it with `ParamArray`

Comment: ParamArray sounds like the right way to go. Unfortunately i'm a novice and don't know how to implement that, so I'm hoping to learn from how a pro on stackexchange does it :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a different, possibly more complicated approach. You can specify the criteria directly on the sheet.

The function is UniqueNames(Range of Data, Range of Names, Range of Rules, Optional AndRules = True, Optional PrintNames = False)

Here is my sample sheet
[image]

I'm using the function 4 times in
- Range("E16") as `UniqueNames(A1:F11,G1:G11,A13:B16,FALSE)`
- Range("E17") as `UniqueNames(A1:F11,G1:G11,A13:B16)`
- Range("F16") as `UniqueNames(A1:F11,G1:G11,A13:B16,FALSE,TRUE)`
- Range("F17") as `UniqueNames(A1:F11,G1:G11,A13:B16,,TRUE)`

The following operators for conditions are acceptable `=,<,>,<=,>=,!=`
The operator must be followed by a single space and either
 - a constant value *e.g. Complete*
 - a function of a value, *e.g. Status(Project#6)*
An empty condition is invalid

Here's the code: *Note: There is a private function as well*

```
Public Function UniqueNames(DataSource As Range, ResultsSource As Range, RulesSource As Range, _
                            Optional AndRules As Boolean = True, Optional PrintNames As Boolean = False) As String
' Return N unique names and who

   ' Split Indexed Expressions
   Dim iChar As Integer
   ' Expression to eval
   Dim Expression() As String
   Dim expr As Variant
   ' Results
   Dim Results As Variant
   ' Get Data into variant array
   Dim Data As Variant
   ' Get Rules into variant array of NRows x 2
   Dim Rules As Variant

   iChar = 0
   Data = DataSource
   If RulesSource.Columns.Count = 1 Then
      Rules = Union(RulesSource, RulesSource.Offset(0, 1))
   ElseIf RulesSource.Columns.Count > 2 Then
      Rules = RulesSource.Resize(RulesSource.Rows.Count, 2)
   Else
      Rules = RulesSource
   End If

   Results = ResultsSource.Resize(ResultsSource.Rows.Count, UBound(Rules))

   For i = LBound(Rules) + 1 To UBound(Rules)
      For j = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
         If Rules(i, 1) = Data(1, j) Then
            ' rules must be "operator condition"
            Expression = Split(Rules(i, 2), " ", 2)
            Expression(1) = Trim(Expression(1))

            ' determine which expression is this
            ' Convert expression when an item of something e.g. EndDate(10)
            iChar = InStr(Expression(1), "(")
            If iChar > 0 Then
               expr = ExprToVal(Data, Left$(Expression(1), iChar - 1), _
                              Mid$(Expression(1), iChar + 1, Len(Expression(1)) - iChar - 1))
            Else
               expr = Expression(1)
            End If

            For k = LBound(Data, 1) + 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
               Results(k, i) = False
               Select Case (Expression(0))
                  Case "="
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) = LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
                  Case "<"
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) < LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
                  Case ">"
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) > LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
                  Case "<="
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) <= LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
                  Case ">="
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) >= LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
                  Case "!="
                     If Data(k, j) <> "" And LCase$(Data(k, j)) <> LCase$(expr) Then Results(k, i) = True
               End Select
            Next k
         End If
      Next j
   Next i

   ' create one list where all three rules are true
   Data = Results
   Set Results = Nothing
   ReDim Results(LBound(Data, 1) + 1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 2) As Variant

   ' results now has the names w/a number representing how many rules were met
   For i = LBound(Data, 1) + 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
      Results(i, 1) = Data(i, 1)
      Results(i, 2) = 0
      For j = LBound(Data, 2) + 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
         If Data(i, j) Then Results(i, 2) = Results(i, 2) + 1
      Next j
   Next i

   ' put that back into data
   Data = Results
   Set Results = Nothing
   Results = ""

   For i = LBound(Data, 1) + 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
      If Data(i, 2) = UBound(Rules, 1) - LBound(Rules, 1) Then
         Results = Results & Data(i, 1) & ";"
      ElseIf AndRules = False And Data(i, 2) > 0 Then
         Results = Results & Data(i, 1) & ";"
      End If
   Next i

   ' split that into expression
   Expression = Split(Results, ";")
   For i = LBound(Expression) To UBound(Expression)
      For j = i + 1 To UBound(Expression)
         If Expression(i) = Expression(j) Then Expression(j) = ""
      Next j
   Next i

   iChar = 0
   Results = ""
   For i = LBound(Expression) To UBound(Expression)
      If Expression(i) <> "" Then
         Results = Results & Expression(i) & ";"
         iChar = iChar + 1
      End If
   Next i

   UniqueNames = ""
   If PrintNames Then
      ' prints number of unique names and the names
      UniqueNames = Results
   Else
      ' prints number of unique names
      UniqueNames = CStr(iChar)
   End If

End Function

Private Function ExprToVal(Data As Variant, expr As String, Index As String) As Variant

   Dim Row As Integer
   Dim Col As Integer
   Dim sCol As Variant

   ' Get what type of data this is
   For i = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
      sCol = Replace(Index, Data(1, i), "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
      If IsNumeric(sCol) Then
         Col = i
         Exit For
      ElseIf LCase$(Left$(Index, Len(Data(1, i)))) = LCase$(Data(1, i)) Then
         Col = i
         Exit For
      End If
   Next i
   ' now find the row of the value
   For i = LBound(Data, 1) + 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
      If LCase$(Data(i, Col)) = LCase$(sCol) Then
         Row = i
         Exit For
      End If
   Next i
   ' find the column of the value
   For i = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
      If LCase$(Data(1, i)) = LCase$(expr) Then
         Col = i
         Exit For
      End If
   Next i

   If Row >= LBound(Data, 1) And Row <= UBound(Data, 1) And _
      Col >= LBound(Data, 2) And Col <= UBound(Data, 2) Then
      ExprToVal = Data(Row, Col)
   Else
      ExprToVal = ""
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks. I will have to come back to give the whole code a closer look later. Having the criteria specified in a separate worksheet range vs in the formula parameters is an interesting tradeoff. My initial reaction is that I would separate the condition operator from the value so that the value can be a link to another cell. Also, would this handle wildcards like `*` or `?` in the conditions?

Comment: I didn't consider adding wildcards, not sure if Excel vba had regex so wildcards would be another task